# Cannot boot RHEL 8 on ASRock DeskMini A300 (AMD Ryzen 5 3400G)

Tags: linux, motherboard, redhat-enterprise-linux, amd-ryzen

I recently purchased an ASRock DeskMini A300W, and parts from the QVL list

- cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G (Picasso series)
- 32GB kit ( 2x16 GB )
- SSD (Western Digital Black M.2 NVMe 1TB)

I upgraded the bios to 3.50

---

RHEL 8.0 installs just fine, no problems.  The BIOS upgrade worked, all my parts/hardware are recognized in UEFI setup.

On boot, I get the following errors:

```
Detected CPU family 17h model 24
Warning: AMD Processor - this hardware has not undergone testing by Red Hat and might not be certified.  Please consult https://hardware.redhat.com for certified hardware.

Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD.BCM.AFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD.BCM.AFN7, 20180531/psparse-516
ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20180531/video-364)
sp5100-tco sp5100-tco: Watchdog hardware is disabled
```

(and nothing after this, halts trying to boot, black screen)

On every RHEL install ever, I get the same thing about AMD not being supported, but it always works, without fail, so I believe the problem is elsewhere.

I believe this is a BIOS problem, but if anyone has been able to get RHEL 8 to work on the DeskMini A300W, please share your parts list.